# Simplest way of getting the longest word in string using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Find the Longest Word in a String:

```
function findLongestWordLength(str) {
  return Math.max(...str.split(" ").map(i => i.length));
}

findLongestWordLength("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```

Comment: what is the question? this is just a code

Comment: And the code works fine! What's the question?

Comment: @DhavalMarthak currently the code returns the *length* of the longest string, not the longest string itself.

Comment: just the code for finding the longest word

Comment: If you're asking about simplest, then yes ES6 syntax and using map is probably the way to go but if you're asking for fastest then you should say that

Comment: split your string with a pattern, loop over array items and find item have the largest length

Comment: [Search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=longest+word+string+javascript+site:stackoverflow.com) for this question. Please read: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Comment: @A.J.Uppal From the OP's comment, _just the code for finding the longest word_ it seems like this is a tutorial rather the question!

Answer (score -2):

You could try splitting on space, and then sort the resulting array by length using a lambda:

```js
var input = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";
var parts = input.split(" ");
parts.sort((a, b) => a.length < b.length ? 1 : -1);
console.log(parts[0]);
```

The first element printed should correspond to the word in the original sentence which is the longest.  Of course, this answer does not cater to ties, but if we wanted to handle ties, we could add more logic to the lambda use to sort.

Comment: Not my downvote, but this can be achieved with a simple loop with O(N - 1) time complexity, when sorting would have an average of O(N log N)

Comment: @Cid They're asking for simplest, not fastest, not lowest time complexity, etc.